# ¿Cómo eliminar puntos, comas y el signo de peso de un String y obtener solo el numero?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo uso de Objeto **Intl.NumberFormat** de **JS** para formatear el numero en **Pesos Colombianos** y tengo el siguiente

**HTML**

```
<label for="p">
  Prueba
  <input type="text" id="f">
</label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');

const options = {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'COP'
}

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  input.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CO', options).format(input.value)
  p.textContent = parseInt(input.value)
})
```

El problema es que al ingresar un numero sucede lo siguiente:

Ingreso el **4** este al formatearlo lo convierte a **$ 4,00**

Entonces al ingresar un nuevo numero el NumberFormart no lo admite y me devuelve un NaN

Solo quiero obtener el numero así **4501818** y no así **$ 4.501.818,00** que como lo tendría por el NumberFormat, pero si quiero verlo así en el input para que el usuario entienda la cantidad a medida que ingrese un valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve y quiero que se mantenga así a medida que ingrese números, pero ingreso otro numero y...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evidentemente tu problema es que pasas te numero a texto y ese texto no es posible convertirlo a número nuevamente, porque tiene un `$` y además los puntos y comas están en formato español. Pero más allá de eso (que tiene fácil solución), tienes un problema de funcionamiento que te impedirá resolver el problema, esto a causa de los decimales. Digamos que quieres ingresar `44`, primero escribes un `4` el código formatea y ahora tienes `$ 4,00`, vuelves a presionar el `4` y te queda `$4,004`. La única forma de escribir `44` es posicionar el cursor entre el `4` y la coma, lo cual es problemático

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás experimentando ocurre porque estás formateando el valor del input cada vez que hay un cambio en el evento 'input'. Esto significa que, cuando ingresas "4" en el input, el valor se formatea como "$4,00" y se muestra en el input. Luego, cuando intentas agregar otro número, como "20", el valor "$4,00" ya no es un número válido y se convierte en NaN.

Intenta de esta manera

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const p = document.querySelector('p'); 
const options = {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'COP'
}

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const inputValue = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
  const formattedValue = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CO', options).format(inputValue);
  
  input.value = formattedValue;
  p.textContent = inputValue;  
});
```

```html
<label for="f">
  Prueba
  <input type="text" id="f">
</label>
```

Comment: Probaste tu código? Veo que algo no funciona como se espera.